# How to calculate a date depending on given granularity and another date in js?

Tags: javascript

I have two dates - `date_to = new Date()` and `date_from` which should be

```
date_from = date_to - 10 * granularity units
```

granularity can be hour, day, week and month

So far I have these constants

```
const MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const MS_PER_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60;
const MS_PER_WEEK = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
```

And I transforming date like so

```
const utc1 = Date.UTC(date_to.getFullYear(), date_to.getMonth(), date_to.getDate());
```

But I'm, now sure how to get my second date by given formula.
All the help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are some problems with trying to do this, depending on the results you want.  If your subtraction causes a date to cross certain Summer Time (US: Daylight Saving Time) thresholds, you would get jumps in hour, and sometimes end up with the wrong hour, even the wrong day.  You can fix this using, for instance, `clonedDateTo.setHour(clonedDateTo.getHour() - diff)`, and similarly for days, with week-difference just being seven days difference.  But I don't know if that would help you.  The date libraries probably all offer help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much have it:

```
date_from = new Date(date_to.getTime() - 10 * granularity);
```

`getTime` returns milliseconds-since-the-Epoch, and your granularity values are in milliseconds, and when you pass a number into `new Date`, it uses it as miliseconds-since-The-Epoch. (You don't technically need the `getTime` call, since using a date in a subtraction expression will trigger its `valueOf` method, which for Dates is the same as `getTime`. But for clarity...)

Example:

```js
const MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
const MS_PER_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60;
const MS_PER_WEEK = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

const date_to = new Date(2018, 8, 1); // Sep 1 2018

const granularity = MS_PER_DAY;

const date_from = new Date(date_to.getTime() - 10 * granularity);

console.log("date_to:     " + date_to.toISOString());
console.log("granularity: MS_PER_DAY");
console.log("date_from:   " + date_from.toISOString());
```